# Deleting the specific time-slot from drop-down

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, timeslots

Im using ionic and angularjs for my app development. I'm having two drop downs, one drop down has minutes and another has time slot. On selecting the mins, time slot based on the selected minutes will be generated in the drop-down. when the specific time slot is selected by the user, it must be removed from the drop-down, so ,that time slot is not available for other users. I'm facing issue in deleting the time slots. I have posted the code of what I have tried. I don't know where I have gone wrong and need your help. Thank you.

Html:

```
        Interval in minutes: <select ng-model="interval" ng-change="setTimeSlots()" ng-options="i for i in intervals"></select>
        <br/>Timeslots:
        <select id="dlSlots" ng-model="selectedTimeslot" ng-options="slot for slot in timeslots">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        </select><br/><br/> Selected timeslot: {{selectedTimeslot}}
        </form><br>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.TimeSlot=function(){
    var slotSelected=$scope.selectedTimeslot;
    var deleteSlot=[];
    deleteSlot.push(slotSelected);
    $scope.timing=slotSelected;
       var dropDown=document.getElementById("dlSlots").selected;
      for(var j=0; j <= dropDown.options.length; j++){
          var _item=$scope.option[j];
          if(_item.selected){
              dropDown.removeChild(dropDown.options[j]);
          }
      }
      $scope.selectedTimeslot = "";
  }
```

Comment: can u provide a fiddle or plunker with real data

Comment: @SaEChowdary the real data are bound to the Database.To which I dont have access

Comment: in that case i can say put a ng-change in second select and pass some unique value to that function .....based on that splice the record in $scope.timeslots

Comment: That didn't work  @SaEChowdary. Or maybe I doing it wrong

Comment: that why i asked for info about intervals and timeslots which ur looping

Comment: Can I share the screen shot @SaEChowdary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128440/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-sree).